# How to pronounce נעמי?

Tags: pronunciation

Is it Naomi or Naami?

Wikipedia says 
"Standard Hebrew Noʻomi, Tiberian Hebrew nåʿå̆mī"

Comment: i heard in english its na oh mee or something like that. but in hebrew i would pronounce it as no3omee

Comment: I don't understand the question. נעמי is Hebrew. How do you pronounce a Hebrew word in English? Are you asking how to transliterate it? Surely there are many systems for doing so. Do you want someone to transcribe the pronunciation in IPA?

Comment: What you are asking (aside from being unrelated to Judaism) is not a clear question. One can transliterate directly which, to my ear, would give one "Na'amee" or one can adapt the name (sort of like how Amora became Gomorrah and Shlomo became Solomon).

Comment: Are you assuming the vowel "a" will be pronounced like a Scotsman? An Australian? A Bostonian?

Comment: You've already provided two pronunciations. Are you looking for more?  Is this a survey?  Are you asking what is the most "correct"?

Comment: @SethJ: The question sounds to me "What is the correct way to pronounce נעמי?

Comment: @gershon since there are two options listed, it seems unanswerable to me.

Comment: @SethJ: Which is the correct one?

Comment: @gershon according to whom?